# gets.chomp invoked first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby. I have created a file ***test.rb*** and it has following code.

```
puts "Enter your First Name"
fname = gets.chomp
puts "Welcome #{fname}"
```

And, when I run this in terminal ***ruby test.rb*** it first shows empty line (waiting from user input). There I entered my name. And then on a new line, it shows "Enter your First Name" then on a new line it shows "Welcome Tanmay"

```
Tanmay
Enter your First Name
Welcome Tanmay
```

It should show "Enter your First Name" before asking for input.

**I am using windows 10, ruby 2.5.1p57, Rails 5.2.0**

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does not reproduce on my machine. Works as expected (although it's macos, not win 10)

Comment: It works as expected on my machine also! Please check if you changed something in your file before running it!

Comment: Works ok on win7 and Sierra. But try add `STDOUT.flush` before the `gets`.

Comment: @iGian Thank you. It works. I added *STDOUT.flush* before *gets*

Comment: @iGian but it's so irritating. I have to add *STDOUT.flush* before every gets statement.

Comment: It worked for me. The same code

Comment: @TanmayVats what does `STDOUT.tty?` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `$stdout.sync = true` to force everything you write to stdout (after that point) to be immediately flushed.

By default ruby will buffer I/O if it thinks it's writing to something non-interactive, because that improves performance when you're e.g. writing to a file.

In this case, it sounds like it's guessing wrong... but it also sounds like your application is unlikely to benefit from ever buffering, so it's safe to just override the default to always be synchronous.